# iOS App Store rejection due to WeChat login requiring app installation; possible to use Web view to log in to WeChat on mobile?

Tags: ios, wechat

An app that I recently submitted to the Apple App Store was rejected, due to the following reason: If the WeChat app is not installed and the user clicks a button "Login with WeChat", a dialog pops up telling the user they must install the WeChat app to log in with it.  (if the app is installed, the user is bumped over to the WeChat app to finish login)

Apple suggested that we instead use a Web View to log the user in via WeChat, however the WeChat guide for mobile login states that mobile apps must log in through the WeChat app:

http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/mobile/login/guide

I'm a little confused here because a previous app I had submitted was approved using this setup.  In the app I'm currently trying to submit, the user is able to skip WeChat login if they wish, so WeChat installation is not required to use the app.  However, it would be nice to be able to tell the user that WeChat is a login option, and that they need to install the WeChat app if they'd like to use it as a login option.

Does anyone know if it's allowable and/or possible (wrt WeChat's system) for an iOS app to log a user in via WeChat using a Web View?  It seems that telling the user that WeChat is an available login option might not be possible otherwise...

Comment: What happens if the we-chat app is not installed? Can they log in with any other options? If they can, then tell Apple that in your response. The We-Chat documentation says that if it is NOT installed, you should HIDE the we-chat button per guidelines.. Therefore you should do that and find some other way of letting the user know.. Otherwise provide multiple login options..

Comment: There are no other login options available in the app.  Yeah, you might be right, especially because it seems that you have to scan a QR code (with your phone) to log into a WeChat web app, which doesn't really make a lot of sense for mobile login...

Comment: If there are no other login options, Apple cannot log in then??? Then how can they test that part of the app? I think maybe I'm misunderstanding..

Comment: I agree with @Brandon, if there's no other option to log in to your app unless WeChat, then how do they test your app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: The question is specifically about whether you can use a Web view to log in to WeChat on mobile, the rest is just explaining the situation to provide context.  (could you imagine the responses if I asked to use a Web View for this without explaining why?)  I've edited the title to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, We don't have any other Webview options to login with Wechat. (as of dated Jan 2018)

I had the same rejection from Apple some time back. After a lot of front and back questions and answers with Apple team, We finally hide the button to login with Wechat when Wechat App is not installed and the review passed. Most of the Chinese apps following the same method AFAIK.

Wechat iOS framework does provide an option to check app installed or not.

`+ (BOOL)isWechatAppInstalled;`

Comment: We ended up hiding the button, as suggested.  It's a  little annoying, as it's hard to let the user know that WeChat is an option, but I guess there's not much we can do there...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the following code, you can check whether the Wechat app is installed in yours phone or not

```
if WXApi.isWXAppInstalled() {

  print("Wechat app is installed")

    } else {

  print("Wechat app is not installed")

    }
```